# Jade with Express - ReferenceError: window is not defined

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I am new to node.js and I'm just trying to learn how to use Express and Jade.  It seems that this line in jade.js is causing some kind of problem: `window.jade = require("jade");`

I can start up my server just fine, but when I visit it in my browser I get this error:

```
ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at C:\Users\User\Desktop\node-js-web\node_modules\jade\jade.js:3142:1
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Desktop\node-js-web\node_modules\jade\jade.js:3143:2)
    at Module._compile (module.js:441:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:459:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:348:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:308:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (module.js:370:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Desktop\node-js-web\node_modules\jade\index.js:4:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:441:26)
```

When I comment out that line I get this error instead:

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'compile'
    at Function.compile (C:\Users\User\Desktop\node-js-web\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:68:33)
    at ServerResponse._render (C:\Users\User\Desktop\node-js-web\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:417:18)
    at ServerResponse.render (C:\Users\User\Desktop\node-js-web\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:318:17)
    at C:\Users\User\Desktop\node-js-web\server.js:37:7
    at callbacks (C:\Users\User\Desktop\node-js-web\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:272:11)
    at param (C:\Users\User\Desktop\node-js-web\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:246:11)
    at pass (C:\Users\User\Desktop\node-js-web\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:253:5)
    at Router._dispatch (C:\Users\User\Desktop\node-js-web\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:4)
    at Object.handle (C:\Users\User\Desktop\node-js-web\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:45:10)
    at next (C:\Users\User\Desktop\node-js-web\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\http.js:203:15)
```

I really don't know what to do here.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `window` object in Node.js because it's not in a browser. If you want to attach `jade` to the global scope, use `global`.

(But why do you want to make the variable global to your application, anyways? Only Express needs the jade object to render your views.)

Comment: This code is in jade.js -- apparently due to some bug work-around? [link](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/issues/247)

Comment: After taking a closer look at your errors, I see that it's failing inside of ``jade.js`` on line ``3142``!? [But ``jade.js`` is only ``238`` lines long](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/blob/master/lib/jade.js). How are you loading the code into Node.js? It doesn't seem like you're doing a simple ``var jade = require('jade')``

Comment: ah ok the package I downloaded from npm was missing /lib/jade.js

Comment: I downloaded the /lib/jade.js file.  It's working now, thanks!

Comment: No problem, though I am surprised that ``npm install jade`` didn't grab that for you from the get-go...